# How to deal with my application's unusual usage of memory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, memory-management, memory-leaks, application-pool

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application hosted on a shared server with the following limitations:

1. 100 MB of RAM
2. 15% of CPU

The host admins say that if an application reaches these limitations, the application pool would be restarted.

After deploying, I noticed that application pool is restarting too quickly (after a few minutes). I used [MonitorAspNetApplication](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/MonitorAspNetApplication) to check memory usage.

By first load, allocated memory is around 8 or 9 MB and used memory around 500 or 600 KB.

But when I start using the application ( CRUD operations, ... ), used memory goes up and down but never goes beyond a few (6-10) megabytes. But the allocated memory increases progressively until it reaches 100 MB and then the application pool resets.

I can't figure out why this is happening. The application is not big, and it doesn't do complicated operations or heavy queries.

I'm using EF code first, StructureMap, AutoMapper and ELMAH in this project.

1. What can be the possible reasons for this problem? How can I to detect and solve them?
2. Can these tools (EF, StructureMap, etc.) cause this memory usage?
3. is this a memory leak ? or it's called something else ?

Comment: you can use PerfView to analyze Memory and CPU usage of .net apps: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial

Comment: thank you for the link , is my situation a memory leak ? or it has a different name ?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to nature of Common Language Runtime. Garbage Collector collects high order generations when there is low memory, but when your app get 100 MB of memory, there is many free memory in  system. You should monitor memory usage by yourself and call GC.Collect when usage is near 100 MB.

Comment: you mean it's normal to reach 100 mg in 3 minutes ? and I should not feel bad about it ?

Comment: If you need to decrease memory usage, you should use memory profiler to discover what is using memory.